# Laravel Class Socialite not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

What I did:

- Added `"laravel/socialite": "~2.0"` to `composer.json`
- Run `composer update`
- Added provider `'Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider'` to `app.php`
- Added alias `'Socialite' => 'Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite'` to `app.php`

After all this steps I created a new Controller Class which looks like that:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthController extends Controller {

    public function login()
    {                  
        return \Socialite::with('facebook')->redirect();
    }

}
```

**But** i still got this error: `PHP Fatal error:  Class '\Socialite'`

**Edit**
`composer dump-autoload` fixed probably the error, but it's still not working correctly.

Comment: Try running `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @lukasgeiter didn't work, but i found something. I accidentally posted  the wrong error message. This is the right one: `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\Socialite'`

Comment: And you are surely using it with a backslash: `return \Socialite` and not just `return Socialite` ?

Comment: @lukasgeiter My bad again. I was to fast.. I am trying now since 3 hours :D with `return \Socialite` i got no error anymore in the apache log, but there is still `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.`

Comment: Then enable debugging or take a look at the laravel log file in `storage/logs`

Comment: @lukasgeiter Nothing. This were the last 2 entries from today: `#48 /var/www/dev/public/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#49 {main}  `

Comment: These two lines are just the end of a stack trace. Are you sure there aren't any errors? normally a `Whoops` page should produce an entry in the logs

Comment: @lukasgeiter I can't believe it.. i found the mistake.. I wrote `client_server` instead of `client_secret`.. don't worry, i have a fund for stupid mistakes like that. Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 9):

In your Controllers file add

```
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
```

Comment: Having the same problem, this one perfectly works for me

Answer (score 7):

Just below `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` in your controller add `use Socialize;`

Answer (score 6):

Check if you have set your alias as "Socialize" as in the Socialite docs says to do this way:

```
'Socialize' => 'Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite',
```

It as very confusing to me as well

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. Clearing the config cache helped me in this situation:

`php artisan config:clear`

Answer (score 3):

First of all use `::class,` on your config/app.php

```
'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,
```

Second, call the class in your controller

```
use Socialite;
```

Third, try clear the config

```
php artisan config:clear
```

And lastly check the redirect URL if its working

```
http://yoursite.com/your_redirect
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone still encounters this problem even after trying above solutions, please clear the cache. Most of the time classes and all are cached because of which this error occurs.

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 1):

`'Socialite' => 'Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite'` is a mistake that I did too.

It must be declared as `'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class`

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and after the usual half hour of raging I realised that there was a trailing space at the end of my registration line i.e.

`'Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider ',`

Once I'd removed the space funnily enough it worked!

`'Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider',`

Once again the woes of copy and paste raise their ugly heads!

Answer (score 0):

in laravel 6 or above, try running this command

`composer require laravel/socialite`